# angucomplete-alt selected object data

Tags: angularjs

in the documentation says that:

selected-object-data -> A second parameter which will be passed to selected-object. I'm trying to use it but the callback function is not receiving it. 
What i'm doing wrong?

```
<div data-angucomplete-alt=""
   id="agent"
   data-placeholder="Type to search"
   data-pause="400"
   data-selected-object="callbackFunction"
   data-selected-object-data="row"
   data-remote-url="getClients?searchString="
   data-remote-url-data-field="Clients"
   data-title-field="CompanyName"
   data-input-class="form-control"
   data-match-class="highlight"
   data-minlength="2"
   data-initial-value="{{row.agentCompany}}"
   data-remote-url-response-formatter="formatAutoCompleteJson">
</div>


$scope.callbackFunction = function (selected) {
    console.log(selected);  //print only the selected object, no the data (second parameter)
    //how to get the second parameter?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out that I was using an older version of the angucomplete, I updated it to the latest version and the parameter start working.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you added a 2nd parameter to your callback function, then you could access the value of "row"

```
$scope.callbackFunction = function (selected, row) {
    console.log(selected);  
    console.log(row); // should print the row number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an initialiser function in the controller, which returns the callback function into the scope of the repeat.

```
<html>
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
...
<div ng-init="row.callbackFunction = initialiseCallback(row)"></div>
<angucomplete-alt selected-object = "row.callbackFunction" />
...
</div>
</html>

Controller() {
    $scope.initialiseCallback = function (row){
        return function function (selected) {
            console.log(selected);  
            console.log(row); // should print the row number
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ng-repeat
for example

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="customer in customers track by $index">
                    <angucomplete-alt pause="500"
                                      selected-object="selectedCustomer"
                                      selected-object-data="$index"
                                      remote-url={{apiURL}}/customers/q?search="
                                      remote-url-data-field="customers"
                                      title-field="surname,name"
                                      description-field="address"
                                      minlength="3"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

If in selected-object-date you bind the $index of ng-repeat
In this case you can have this situation

```
  $scope.selectedCustomer = function(customer, index) {
    console.log(customer, index);
  };
```